# jquery add class to div, add another class to all others

Tags: jquery

I have a couple divs, when I hover I want to add a class to the hovered div, but at the same time i want to add another class to all the divs that are not hovered, here is my code:

I know this is a simple fix, I am overlooking sometime (or really tired lol)

HTML:

```
<div class="event"></div>
<div class="event"></div>
<div class="event"></div>
<div class="event"></div>
<div class="event"></div>
<div class="event"></div>
<div class="event"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".event" ).hover(
function() {
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hovered");
}
);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add a class to the hovered div, but at the same time i want
>   to add another class to all the divs that are not hovered

Keep the elements in a variable, that way you can just target everything but not `this`

```
var elems = $( ".event" );

elems.hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
        elems.not(this).addClass('something_else')
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hovered");
        elems.not(this).removeClass('something_else')
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
$('div').hover(function () { // on a hover on a div
   $('div').attr('class', 'event'); // remove the class; keep the first one
   $(this).attr('class', 'hovered event'); // update the class for the current
}
```

This uses the `attr` from the jQuery API to update and replace the attribute values. Hope it helps you.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/SVRcw/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.not()` to exclude the current element from the overall element collection.

Try,

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {

var xElements = $(".event");

$( ".event" ).hover(
function() {
    xElements.not($(this)).addClass('anotherClass');
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
    xElements.removeClass("hovered");
    $(".event").not($(this)).removeClass('anotherClass');
}
);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `not()`
try this

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   var $event=$('.event');
   $event.hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("hovered");
      $event.not(this).addClass("newClass");
   }, function() {
      $event.not(this).removeClass("newClass");
    });
});
```